# Generate c# class structure from JSON Schema - online generator

Tags: c#, json, jsonschema

Looking for a quick and dirty tool to generate a C# class structure for a given JSON Schema.

Something like this http://json2csharp.rohitl.com/ (I don't like the output of this)

I also found https://app.quicktype.io/. Are there others?

Comment: Have you tried Visual Studio? Copy your json string and go to **Edit > Paste Special > Past Json As Classes**

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for [so] as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @RuiJarimba, That will generate classes from json, not from json schema.

Comment: Oh sorry, you're absolutely right